# beforeRouteEnter doesn't work in vue child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I try to detect what is the previous route in my component. I use `beforeRouteEnter` to find it. it works in **CreditAdd.vue** but when I use `beforeRouteEnter` in **Back.vue** it doesn't work!

I think it because the Back component is a child. but I can't solve the problem

Back.vue:

```js
<template>
  <i class="bi ba-arrow-right align-middle ml-3" style="cursor: pointer" @click="handleBack"></i>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Back',
  data() {
    return {
      id: null
    };
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    console.log('please log');
    next(vm => {
      vm.fromRoute = from;
    });
  },
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    handleBack() {
      if (!this.fromRoute.name) {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' });
      } else {
        this.$router.back();
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

CreditAdd.vue:

```html
<template>
  <Layout>
    <template slot="header">
      <Back />
      <span>افزایش اعتبار</span>
    </template>

    <div class="col-lg-10 px-0">
      <Card>
        <template v-if="type == 'select'">
          <credit-add-way @select="changeType"></credit-add-way>
        </template>

        <template v-if="type == 'bank'">
          <credit-add-bank-way @back="changeType('select')"></credit-add-bank-way>
        </template>

        <template v-if="type == 'code'">
          <credit-add-code-way @back="changeType('select')"></credit-add-code-way>
        </template>
      </Card>
    </div>
  </Layout>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

`beforeRouteEnter` and other navigation guards should only works on the Vue file that is defined the link in the router, thats why **Back.vue** not working.

You can use plain javascript to get the previous URL
in **Back.vue**

```
mounted() {
  console.log(document.referrer);
}
```

Another way is you can store the previous route in Vuex store,

In **AddCredit.vue** where navigation guards work

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    // store this in vuex
  },
```

then in **Back.vue** can just retrieve right away from the store